# Change the text of a "TextView" from onListItemClick

Tags: android, xml

Changing the text of a TextView from the onListItemClick ListFragment method of a class.
This is the method:

```
 @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

        Descripcion_Noticias myDetailFragment = new Descripcion_Noticias();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        myDetailFragment.setText(v,selectedValue);

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, myDetailFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }
```

The xml is:

The XMl is in new fragment, extend fragment.

---

The XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/ss"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The method of ListFragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        CharSequence s =selectedValue;
        TextView t = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ss);
        t.setText(s);

        Descripcion_Noticias myDetailFragment = new Descripcion_Noticias();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, myDetailFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }

The class primary of XMl: 

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.descripcion_noticias, null);
        return v;

    }
```

---

Method:

```
    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    CharSequence s =selectedValue;
    mTextView.setText(s);

    Descripcion_Noticias myDetailFragment = new Descripcion_Noticias();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, myDetailFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

}

The class fragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.descripcion_noticias, null);
   mTextView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById (R.id.ss);
    return v;

}
```

The twos class has   `private TextView mTextView;`

Comment: No function: TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ss);
        t.setText(s);

Comment: It would be great if you put the stacktrace output of the error.

Comment: The error is: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: It's clear that v.findViewById(R.id.ss); is returning null, try with getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ss);

Comment: Or if onListItemClick is placed in the activity just remove the "v.".

Comment: Also, try to put the complete code (the activity, fragment and XML).

Comment: If I use getActivity and getView, the error is the same. Pressing an item from the list, the app is closed. @EuryPérezBeltré

Comment: Post the whole code so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onCreateView method, save a global reference to your TextView:

```
mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ss);
```

And then access it in your onListItemClick as:

```
mTextView.setText(s);
```

**EDIT**

In the top of the class you put:

```
private TextView mTextView;
```

In your listener method:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    CharSequence s =selectedValue;
    mTextView.setText(s);

    Descripcion_Noticias myDetailFragment = new Descripcion_Noticias();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, myDetailFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


}
```

The class primary of XMl:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.descripcion_noticias, null);
    mTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ss);
    return v;

}
```

Comment: Add line: TextView mTextView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById (R.id.ss);

And methdo "onListItemClick": 
    TextView t = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ss);
        t.setText(s);

Comment: Add it as a global reference. In the top you need to have something like:
private TextView mTextView

Comment: Follow the same problem-

Comment: I don't think you are following my instructions correctly nor giving me all the information.

Comment: Display my other comment.